# If G is the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ show that mG = G for any $m \epsilon \mathbb{N}^+$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Def: $mG$ = {$ma$ | $a \epsilon$ G}

To show $mG = G$ I can show $mG \subseteq G$ and $G \subseteq mG$.

To show $mG \subseteq G$:

Take $x \epsilon mG$. Then $x$ has the form $m$($\mathbb{Z} + \frac{a}{b}$) = $m\mathbb{Z} + \frac{ma}{b}$ for some $a,b \epsilon \mathbb{Z}$.

How can I show $m\mathbb{Z} + \frac{ma}{b}$ is of the form $\mathbb{Z} + \frac{a}{b}$?

To show $G \subseteq mG$:

Let $x \epsilon G$. Then $x = \mathbb{Z} + \frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b \epsilon \mathbb{Z}$.

Again I have the same problem of proving x is also of the form $m\mathbb{Z} + \frac{ma}{b}$.

Comment: Are you sure the operation is multiplication, and not addition?

Comment: $m({\mathbb Z}+\frac{a}{b}) = {\mathbb Z} + \frac{ma}{b}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $mG=G$, it's enough to show that for any $x\in G$ there exists $y\in G$ with $my=x$. And if $x=r+\mathbb{Z}$, let $y=\frac{1}{m}r+\mathbb{Z}$.